# Error when using random effect with h2o.glm in R

Tags: r, h2o, glm

I would like to use h2o in `R` for glm regression but with random effects (HGLM, seems possible from [this page](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/hglm.html) ). I do not manage to make it work yet, and get errors I do not understand.

Is here my working example: I define a dataset with Simpson paradox: a global increasing trend, but a decreasing trend in each group

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(h2o)
library(data.table)

global_slope <- 1
global_int <- 1

Npoints_per_group <- 50
N_groups <- 10
pentes <- rnorm(N_groups,-1,.5)

centers_x <- seq(0,10,length = N_groups)
center_y <- global_slope*centers_x + global_int

group_spread <- 2

group_names <- sample(LETTERS,N_groups)

df <- lapply(1:N_groups,function(i){
  x <- seq(centers_x[i]-group_spread/2,centers_x[i]+group_spread/2,length = Npoints_per_group)
  y <- pentes[i]*(x- centers_x[i])+center_y[i]+rnorm(Npoints_per_group)
  data.table(x = x,y = y,ID = group_names[i])
}) %>% rbindlist()
```

You can recognize something similar to the example of the [wiki page of Simpson paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color = as.factor(ID)))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The linear regression without random effect sees the increasing trend:

```
lm(y~x,data = df) %>% 
summary()

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.28187    0.13077   9.803   <2e-16 ***
x            0.94147    0.02194  42.917   <2e-16 ***
```

A standard multilevel regression would look like that:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

lmer( y ~ x + (1+x|ID) ,data = df) %>% 
  summary()
```

And would estimate properly a decreasing trend:

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  11.7192     2.6218  8.8220   4.470 0.001634 ** 
x            -1.0418     0.1959  8.9808  -5.318 0.000486 ***
```

Now I test with `h2o`:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

df2 <- as.h2o(df)
test_glm <- h2o.glm(family = "gaussian",
                        x = "x",
                        y = "y",
                        training_frame = df2,
                        lambda = 0,
                        compute_p_values = TRUE)
test_glm
```

And it works well, similar to the linear model above:

```
Coefficients: glm coefficients
      names coefficients std_error   z_value  p_value standardized_coefficients
1 Intercept     1.281868  0.130766  9.802785 0.000000                  5.989232
2         x     0.941473  0.021937 42.916536 0.000000                  3.058444
```

But when I want to use random effects:

```
test_glm2 <- h2o.glm(family = "gaussian",
                     x = "x",
                     y = "y",
                     training_frame = df2,
                     random_columns = "ID",
                     lambda = 0,
                     compute_p_values = TRUE)
```

I got

> Error in .h2o.checkAndUnifyModelParameters(algo = algo, allParams = ALL_PARAMS, : vector of random_columns must be of type numeric, but got character.

Even if I force `df2$ID  <- as.numeric(df2$ID)`.

What Am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to find something similar to the mixed effect model with `lmer` (i.e. random slope and intercept)?

---

## EDIT

I changed to use, as suggested by Erin LeDell, the column number. I now get a different error, that I do not understand either:

```
df2$ID  <- as.factor(df2$ID)

test_glm2 <- h2o.glm(family = "gaussian",
                     x = "x",
                     y = "y",
                     training_frame = df2,
                     random_columns = c(3),
                     HGLM = TRUE,
                     lambda = 0,
                     compute_p_values = TRUE)

DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
    at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:660)
    at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:670)
    at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:530)
    at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:482)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitCoeffs(GLM.java:1334)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitHGLM(GLM.java:1505)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitModel(GLM.java:2060)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeSubmodel(GLM.java:2526)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.doCompute(GLM.java:2664)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeImpl(GLM.java:2561)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:247)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.compute2(GLM.java:1188)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1658)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:976)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

---

## Edit 2:

I actually found a way to remove the above error, by adding

```
rand_link = c("identity"),
rand_family = c("gaussian"),
```

to the `h2o.glm` arguments:

```
h2o.glm(family = "gaussian",
                     rand_link = c("identity"),
                     rand_family = c("gaussian"),
                     # compute_p_values = TRUE,
                     x = "x",
                     y = "y",
                     training_frame = df2,
                     random_columns = c(3),
                     HGLM = TRUE,
                     lambda = 0)
```

Works. But when I set `compute_p_values = TRUE`, and then find a new error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

degrees of freedom (0)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things wrong with the code (we need to do a better job of documenting the [`random_columns`](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/random_columns.html) parameter).  Currently the `random_columns` parameter only supports column indexes (not column names) and I created a [JIRA](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8648) to improve this.

The error is not actually saying that the column has to be numeric; in fact it needs to be a factor.  And lastly, you need to set `HGLM = TRUE`.  To fix your code above, you can do:

```
df2$ID2 <- as.factor(df2$ID2)

test_glm2 <- h2o.glm(family = "gaussian",
                     x = "x",
                     y = "y",
                     training_frame = df2,
                     random_columns = c(4),
                     HGLM = TRUE,
                     lambda = 0,
                     compute_p_values = TRUE)
```

EDIT: This still causes a bug, so I filed a bug report [here](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8656).

Comment: Thank you Erin! Yes the doc was not very clear, but I could have guessed from the example given

Comment: I am still getting an error:
`Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I edited my question to report the new error. I tried on two different machine, one windows, one linux, and got the same error

Comment: There was a typo in my code above (wrong column index) but I fixed it and the bug is still there (will try to follow-up soon with an answer/fix).

Comment: Yep I spotted the typo, but did not though about correcting it, sorry. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added a link to the JIRA ticket -- this is indeed a bug.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but the problem seems to come from the `compute_p_values = TRUE` argument: when removing it, it works.